# Unwanted StatusBar with Google Play Services

Tags: libgdx, statusbar, google-play-services

I recently implemented Google Play Game Services to my "libgdx" game following [this tutorial](http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u1070589/blog/?p=202), and for some reason after doing that StatusBar appeared and I can't get rid of it.

I have searched for the answer all over the internet but I cant find anything about this issue. Has anyone run into this problem?